# Devise helper methods do not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for authenticating users in my app. The problem is that none of the devise helpers exist in my app. For example. In file `app/controllers/admin/dashboard.php` I have this snippet of code:

```
<% if user_signed_in ? %>
   do something
<% end %>
```

I get

```
undefined method `user_signed_in?'
```

Here is the output of the `rake routes` command

```
new_admin_session           GET    /admin/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
admin_session               POST   /admin/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
destroy_admin_session       DELETE /admin/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
admin_password              POST   /admin/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
new_admin_password          GET    /admin/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
edit_admin_password         GET    /admin/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                            PUT    /admin/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_registration   GET    /admin/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
admin_registration          POST   /admin(.:format)                 devise/registrations#create
new_admin_registration      GET    /admin/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
edit_admin_registration     GET    /admin/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                            PUT    /admin(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                            DELETE /admin(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
login                              /admin/login(.:format)           devise/sessions#new
login                              /admin(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
admin_dashboard_index       GET    /admin/dashboard/index(.:format) admin/dashboard#index
```

Here is the content of routes.rb

```
devise_for :admin

  devise_scope :admin do
    match 'admin/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :login
    match 'admin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :login
    get "admin/dashboard/index"
  end

  namespace :admin do
    resources :images
  end
```

And Admin model

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me 

end
```

What is wrong here? I'm able to register or log-in, but I can't use helper methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your model is `Admin` you have to call

```
admin_signed_in?
```

and also

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
```

in your controller.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#configuring-multiple-models

Answer (score 1):

try

```
admin_logged_in?
```

devise will use whatever the model is called